# How to use Multiprocessing in Python within a class

Tags: python, oop, python-multiprocessing

What I'd like to do is use multiprocessing on one of my class methods. I have tried to follow the example in the Python help file but am not getting the result expected. Here is my class file:

```
import os
import telnetlib

class PowerSupply():

    # ---------------------------------- #
    def __init__(self,port_no,my_name):
        self.Status = "Off"
        self.Port = port_no
        self.Name = my_name
        self.tn = None
        self.HOST = "192"
        self.P = Process(target=self.print_time, args=('tname','delay')
        self.P.start()
        self.P.join()
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def TurnOn(self):
        onCommand = "OUT 1\r"

        if self.Status == "ON":
            print "I'm already on"
        else:
            self.tn = telnetlib.Telnet(self.HOST,self.Port)
            self.tn.write(onCommand)
            self.Status = "ON"
            print "I am now on"
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def TurnOff(self):
        offCommand = "OUT 0\r"
        self.tn.write(offCommand)
        self.tn.close()
        print "I am now off"
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def SetVoltage(self,volts):
        voltageCommand = "PV" + " " + str(volts) + "\r"
        self.tn.write(voltageCommand)
    # ---------------------------------- #  
    def GetAllData(self):
        while(self.Status == "ON"):
            self.tn.write("DVC?\r")
            all_data = self.tn.read_some()
            vdc = all_data.split(',')
            vdc = vdc[0]
            print vdc
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def print_time(self, tname, delay):
       count = 0
       while count < 5:
        time.sleep(delay)
        count += 1
        print "%s: %s"%(tname, time.ctime(time.time()))
```

Here is how I try to use the implementation:

```
ps1 = PowerSuppy(8000,'L1')
ps1.print_time('thread1',2)
ps1.print_time('thread2',3)
```

When I try to use it as above, it still uses a procedural approach and doesn't call the thread2 until thread1 is complete. What is it exactly that I am doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your code has syntax error (`self.P = Process(target=self.print_time, args=('tname','delay')`), did you miss lines?

Comment: Just a close parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's what I suppose the program will do:

1. At `PowerSuppy(8000,'L1')`, it starts a subprocess and calls `self.print_time('tname','delay')`. Since `'delay'` is not a number it immediately raises a `TypeError` in the subprocess and end (so `self.P.join()` didn't block at all).
2. At `ps1.print_time('thread1',2)`, it runs the method in main process and is blocked until it end.
3. `ps1.print_time('thread2',3)` does the same thing as the previous line did in main process.

How to fix it:

1. Do not initialize the subprocess in `__init__` method, instead, initialize it in `print_time` method.
2. Implemented a internal method for `target` function for subprocess.
3. Do not run `Process.join` unless you want to run the subprocess in sequence.

Here's the code:

```
import os
import telnetlib

class PowerSupply():

    # ---------------------------------- #
    def __init__(self,port_no,my_name):
        self.Status = "Off"
        self.Port = port_no
        self.Name = my_name
        self.tn = None
        self.HOST = "192"

    # ---------------------------------- #
    def TurnOn(self):
        onCommand = "OUT 1\r"

        if self.Status == "ON":
            print "I'm already on"
        else:
            self.tn = telnetlib.Telnet(self.HOST,self.Port)
            self.tn.write(onCommand)
            self.Status = "ON"
            print "I am now on"
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def TurnOff(self):
        offCommand = "OUT 0\r"
        self.tn.write(offCommand)
        self.tn.close()
        print "I am now off"
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def SetVoltage(self,volts):
        voltageCommand = "PV" + " " + str(volts) + "\r"
        self.tn.write(voltageCommand)
    # ---------------------------------- #  
    def GetAllData(self):
        while(self.Status == "ON"):
            self.tn.write("DVC?\r")
            all_data = self.tn.read_some()
            vdc = all_data.split(',')
            vdc = vdc[0]
            print vdc
    # ---------------------------------- #
    def print_time(self, tname, delay):
        P = Process(target=self._print_time, args=(tname, delay))
        P.start()

    def _print_time(tname, delay):
        count = 0
        while count < 5:
            time.sleep(delay)
        count += 1
        print "%s: %s"%(tname, time.ctime(time.time()))
```

Comment: Closures aren't pickleable; they're no good for `multiprocessing`. Same goes for `lambda`s. You can only pickle top level functions, or methods of pickleable classes.

Comment: @Philip Tzou, your solution works great! One thing I'd like to point out is, when I test the new class/method, it works fine in the Python Interpreter, but I get no response back in IDLE. When i run it in IDLE, it returns absolutely nothing. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @DeeTee You mean it doesn't work in IDLE at all or just not output?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a function in your class:

```
def print_time_subprocess(self, tname, delay):
    p = Process(target=self.print_time, args=('tname','delay'))
    p.start()
```

and use this to test:

```
ps1 = PowerSupply(8000,'L1')
ps1.print_time_subprocess('thread1',2)
ps1.print_time_subprocess('thread2',3)
```

and do not forget import `Process`